# Creating multiple WebSockets

Tags: gwt, websocket

Can someone tell me what would happen If I create more than one WebSocket and try to use them to send some data to server?
Will this work or will I get some error?

P.S.: I ask this question because of I use the GWT framework... Client code is written in pure Java (actually the client-side emulated subset of pure Java) while JavaScript is used in order to create the *webSocket* connections.
But I want to use webSocket in some other place too, so either I must rely on order of code execution. Secondly I think to reuse the already created JavaScript webSocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is necessary to do in order to get what I demand is to write:

```
$wnd.socketVar = new $wnd.WebSocket(server1)
```

In any other place it is possible to access exactly that web socket throught: $wnd.socketVar.

Answer (score 1):

Does that answer your question?

```
var socket1 = new window.WebSocket("ws://server1.com");
var socket2 = new window.WebSocket("ws://server2.com");

socket1.send("hello 1"); // will send to server1.com
socket2.send("hello 2"); // will send to server2.com
```

You send via a method on a specific WebSocket object.

Comment: Not at all ! What I asked is: consider some class MyFirstWidget.java. And there a write the following code: var socket1 = new @wnd.WebSocket(server1);    And consider I also have MySecondWidget.java from where I would like to send and get back some data too from that socket. The question was - is it save and sound for me to write there ( in second file ): var socket2 = new @wnd.WebSocket(server1); and use it, or not ?      I suppose, the root of the question is in I do not know how to create a Global JavaScript variable in GWT project and use it.